# Cakephp can't load css and js files

Tags: cakephp

I have a cakephp application running in local server (Ampps for mac). when I type the url in the navigator I can't see css and js files loaded. When I check the console I find these errors :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/app/webroot/files/masque_maroc.geojson:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/maps/display_time_filter_box:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/maps/display_filter_box:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/maps/get_data:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/maps/categories_menu:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/maps/mobile_categories_menu:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I did some researches, I found that I had to edit my .htaccess files of /app and Applications/AMPPS/www/carte_drin folders, I also added another one directly in www folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /Applications/AMPPS/www/carte_drin/app
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(app/webroot/)?(img|css|js)/(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Yet the error is still there

Some says that I have to delete all .htaccess files and uncomment

```
Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));
```

of app/config/core.php yet the erros perist I don't know what I'm missing. Your help would precious thank you!

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means that the following `RewriteRule` **does not** apply if a matching file exists. Please check if `mod_rewrite` is enabled in your environment. You could do so by placing `phpinfo();` inside a PHP file on the server and search for `mod_rewrite` on the resulting page. If it is enabled, please post the contents of all `.htaccess` files, which CakePHP version you are using and where your JS and CSS files are located.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set `AllowOverride All` correctly , Look at the following pic and double check your   and make sure you are editing `www` path and `VirtualHost` is 127.0.0.1

[image: Please make sure your Apache.conf is set correctly]